# Why is my SQL 'NOT IN' clause producing different results from 'NOT EXISTS'

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have two SQL queries producing different results when I would expect them to produce the same result. I am trying to find the number of events that do not have a corresponding location. All locations have an event but events can also link to non-location records.

The following query produces a count of 16244, the correct value.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT e.event_id)   
FROM   events AS e   
WHERE  NOT EXISTS   
  (SELECT * FROM locations AS l WHERE l.event_id = e.event_id)
```

The following query produces a count of 0.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT e.event_id) 
FROM   events AS e
WHERE  e.event_id NOT IN (SELECT  l.event_id FROM locations AS l)
```

The following SQL does some summaries of the data set

```
SELECT  'Event Count', 
        COUNT(DISTINCT event_id) 
        FROM events

UNION ALL

SELECT  'Locations Count', 
        COUNT(DISTINCT event_id) 
        FROM locations

UNION ALL

SELECT  'Event+Location Count', 
        COUNT(DISTINCT l.event_id) 
        FROM locations AS l  JOIN events AS e ON l.event_Id = e.event_id
```

And returns the following results

```
Event Count         139599
Locations Count         123355
Event+Location Count    123355
```

Can anyone shed any light on why the 2 initial queries do not produce the same figure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a NULL in the subquery `SELECT  l.event_id FROM locations AS l` so NOT IN [will always evaluate to unknown and return 0 results](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/sql-and-the-snare-of-three-valued-logic/)

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT e.event_id) 
FROM   events AS e
WHERE  e.event_id NOT IN (SELECT  l.event_id FROM locations AS l)
```

The reason for this behaviour can be seen from the below example.

> 'x' NOT IN (NULL,'a','b')
>
> ≡ 'x' <> NULL and 'x' <> 'a' and 'x'
>   <> 'b'
>
> ≡ Unknown and True and True
>
> ≡ Unknown

Comment: @Pacerier This answer is 5 years old so can't remember for sure. Probably I was already aware of the article having previously come across it though.

Answer (score 5):

The `NOT IN` form works differently for NULLs. The presence of a single `NULL` will cause the entire statement to fail, thus returning no results.

So you have at least one `event_id` in `locations` that is `NULL`.

Also, your query might be better written as a join:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(DISTINCT e.event_id)    
FROM
    events AS e  
    LEFT JOIN locations AS l ON e.event_id = l.event_id
WHERE
    l.event_id IS NULL
```

[UPDATE: apparently, the `NOT EXISTS` version is faster.]

Comment: +1 Thanks. Out of interest why would it be better written as a join? The Joined version is marginally slower for my dataset but both the exists and the join are treated in a very similar fashion according to the execution plan but the JOIN does a Merge Join (Left Outer) and the  EXISTS does a Merge Join (Left Anti Semi)

Comment: @Steve It wouldn't. See http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2010/03/23/left-outer-join-vs-not-exists/

Comment: @Mitch - RE: `SELECT 1` That's something I'm not sure about. I believe this used to make a difference but now they will use exactly the same plan but I have noticed Phil Factor still uses it (e.g. http://www.simple-talk.com/community/blogs/philfactor/archive/2009/08/03/74227.aspx). I'm not sure if this is out of habit or for some other reason.

Answer (score -1):

**In** and **Exists** are processed very very differently.

```
Select * from T1 where x in ( select y from T2 )
```

is typically processed as:

```
select * 
  from t1, ( select distinct y from t2 ) t2
 where t1.x = t2.y;
```

The subquery is evaluated, distinct'ed, indexed (or hashed or sorted) and then joined to 
the original table -- typically.

As opposed to

```
select * from t1 where exists ( select null from t2 where y = x )
```

That is processed more like:

```
for x in ( select * from t1 )
   loop
      if ( exists ( select null from t2 where y = x.x )
      then 
         OUTPUT THE RECORD
      end if
   end loop
```

It always results in a full scan of T1 whereas the first query can make use of an index 
on T1(x).

Comment: In my particular case the query optimizer uses exactly the same query plan for both queries.