# Delete sql rows where IDs do not have a match from another table

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm trying to delete orphan entries in a mysql table.

I have 2 tables like this:

Table `files`:

| id | .... |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | .... |
| 2 | .... |
| 7 | .... |
| 9 | .... |

table `blob`:

| fileid | .... |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | .... |
| 2 | .... |
| 3 | .... |
| 4 | .... |
| 4 | .... |
| 4 | .... |
| 9 | .... |

The `fileid` and `id` columns can be used to join the tables together.

I want to delete all rows in table `blob` where `fileid` cannot be found in the table `files.id`.

So using the example above that would delete rows: 3 & 4(s) in the `blob` table.

Comment: Skip to the **second answer** if you are using `null`s.

Answer (score 422, accepted):

### Using LEFT JOIN/IS NULL:

```
DELETE b FROM BLOB b 
  LEFT JOIN FILES f ON f.id = b.fileid 
      WHERE f.id IS NULL
```

### Using NOT EXISTS:

```
DELETE FROM BLOB 
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL
                    FROM FILES f
                   WHERE f.id = fileid)
```

### Using NOT IN:

```
DELETE FROM BLOB
 WHERE fileid NOT IN (SELECT f.id 
                        FROM FILES f)
```

### Warning

Whenever possible, perform DELETEs within a transaction (assuming supported - IE: Not on MyISAM) so you can use rollback to revert changes in case of problems.

Comment: which is, in general, the fastest of the above?

Comment: @HampusBrynolf: This is MySQL specific - it depends on if the columns [are nullable](http://explainextended.com/2010/05/27/left-join-is-null-vs-not-in-vs-not-exists-nullable-columns/) or [are not nullable](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/)

Comment: For some reason, deleting using the LEFT JOIN didn't work on MS SQL Server Mgmt Studio (not sure why; it just complained about the LEFT JOIN). Anyone knows why is that? It worked using NOT EXISTS though :)

Comment: FYI, here's a useful discussion of the relative efficiency of these three methods: http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/

Comment: @OMGPonies, For the `exists` part, Why do you use `select null` instead of `select *`? Isn't it recommended to use `select *`?

Comment: @OMGPonies, Your answers [are wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3384137/632951) because it makes the implicit assumption that the columns are `not null`.

Comment: What if the BLOB table is in an attached/separate DB? Thanks!

Comment: As my observation, DELETE NOT IN is the slowest one, sometimes hundred times slower. NOT EXISTS and LEFT JOIN is much more faster. LEFT JOIN is a bit faster than NOT EXISTS. Of course it depends on your table structure. But generally NOT IN queries runs slower.

Comment: @Pacerier - "wrong" is a bit strong. To make sure people understand, the answers *do* work if `fileid`is *non-nullable*. Also, the third solution (`NOT IN`) only requires that `f.id` by non-nullable. Presumably that is a primary key, so it would be.

Comment: In addition, the only "wrong" consequence of the first two, is that they will not delete rows of BLOB where `fileid` is null. (Actually, the first one might - to be sure, I'd have to test it.)  BTW, for robust design, it should be a non-nullable field.

Comment: For people attempting this w/SQLite: see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4967229/786356)

Comment: For some reason the MySQL on my host server would only execute the first method. Even then, the PHPMyAdmin 4.5.1 syntax checker wouldn't accept anything between `DELETE` and `FROM`, but the query ran ok anyway when I pressed Go.

Comment: Why is `f` needed in the 3. solution?

Comment: What is the difference between NOT EXISTS and NOT IN?

Comment: Found that "DELETE FROM x..."  throws error and "DELETE x FROM x..." works alright. Found it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763206/deleting-rows-with-mysql-left-join

Answer (score 33):

```
DELETE FROM blob 
WHERE fileid NOT IN 
       (SELECT id 
        FROM files 
        WHERE id is NOT NULL/*This line is unlikely to be needed 
                               but using NOT IN...*/
      )
```

Comment: What is *"/*This line is unlikely to be needed 
                               but using NOT IN...*/"* supposed to mean?

Comment: @Pacerier - `NOT IN (NULL)` returns an empty result set so NULLs need to be excluded. But an `id` column probably won't be nullable anyway hence "unlikely to be needed"

Comment: Wow good catch. So the answer by omgponies is wrong! `not in(null)` is pretty logical, Why does it not work? What's the rationale behind that?

Comment: @Pacerier [because `unknown` and anything is either `false` or `unknown` and can never evaluate to `true`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2973572/73226)

Comment: What if the BLOB table is in an attached/separate DB? Thanks!

Comment: @bunkerdive Then use three part object names that include the database name.

Comment: @MartinSmith ...sry, I'm sucha noob. That means DB.Table.Col?

Comment: @Pacerier - The important sentence is "This line is unlikely to be needed". `id` traditionally is a non-nullable primary key.

Answer (score 22):

```
DELETE FROM blob
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM files
    WHERE id=blob.id
)
```

Comment: I think there is a `files.id` and `blob.fileid`. I'm guessing your query will result in an error.

Answer (score 2):

```
DELETE FROM <table> 
WHERE <row column you want to delete by > not in 
(select <column you want to compare other column> from <other table>)
```

This deletes the row when
the first column doesn't appear on the second table