# Deleting rows from SQLite table when no match exists in another table

Tags: sqlite, left-join, sql-delete

I need to delete rows from an SQLite table where their row IDs do not exist in another table. The SELECT statement returns the correct rows:

```
SELECT * FROM cache LEFT JOIN main ON cache.id=main.id WHERE main.id IS NULL;
```

However, the delete statement generates an error from SQLIte:

```
DELETE FROM cache LEFT JOIN main ON cache.id=main.id WHERE main.id IS NULL;
```

The error is: *SQLite Error 1 - near "left": syntax error.* Is there another syntax I could use?

Comment: To explain: I am deleting rows from the "main" table using an additional where condition, to preserve any rows user has marked as "locked" (i.e., should not be deleted until unlocked):

DELETE FROM main WHERE id = ? AND locked = 0;

Each successful delete must be followed by deleting a matching row from the "cache" table, but SQlite does not return a value that would let me know whether the first delete statement actually matched any rows. So instead I tried to delete "unmatched" rows from the cache table, and snagged on the left join.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

SQLite apparently doesn't support joins with the delete statement, as you can see on the [Syntax diagrams](http://www.sqlite.org/syntaxdiagrams.html#delete-stmt). You should however be able to use a subquery to delete them.

ie.

```
DELETE FROM cache WHERE id IN
(SELECT cache.id FROM cache LEFT JOIN main ON cache.id=main.id WHERE main.id IS NULL);
```

(Not tested)

Comment: Thanks! I got very close to this before I read your answer, except I was using equals instead of IN, so my attempt didn't quite work as intended.

Answer (score 20):

Since you going down the route of subquery, might as well get rid of the join altogether and simplify the query:

```
DELETE FROM cache WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id from main);
```

Comment: Not an ideal solution if `main` contains millions of rows. Best to do the join first.

Comment: @Jacob Hopefully someone isn't doing millions of rows in sqlite in the first place.

Comment: If your tables don't have primary keys, you can hack one on the fly, for example: `DELETE FROM cache WHERE x || ',' || y NOT IN (SELECT x || ',' || y from main);`

Comment: @fluffy, don't underestimate SQLite :) it's perfectly reasonable to use it to handle millions of rows, but even if it's a few thousands, this `SELECT id FROM` query is needlessly inefficient and slow. @winvds answer is a much better option.

Comment: `DELETE FROM cache WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT main.id from main WHERE main.id=cache.id)`

Answer (score 0):

Solution from @wimvds didn't work for me, so I modified the query and removed WHERE condition:

```
DELETE FROM FirstTable WHERE firstTableId NOT IN (SELECT SecondTable.firstTableId FROM SecondTable LEFT JOIN FirstTable ON FirstTable.firstTableId=SecondTable.firstTableId)
```

This deletes all the rows from FirstTable that do not have their id assigned to any row in SecondTable.