# SQLite: remove all rows except those whose foreign key has a particular value

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm fairly new  to SQL and I have the following question:

I'm making an android app that stores 3 tables into a database.

- Movies, associated with a custom class I called Movie
- Trailers, associated with a custom class I called Trailer
- Reviews, associated with a custom class I called Review

When an event is triggered by the app, I want to create a SQL statement that will delete all movies that are not marked as favorite. Also, it has to delete every trailer and review associated with a movie that is not marked as favourite.
To mark a movie as favorite, I added an integer column that can have 3 values: (0,1,2). When the movie entry has a value of 2, it is a favorite and, therefore, must NOT be deleted.

This is the structure of my tables:

```
        //SQL statement to create the movies table
    final String SQL_CREATE_FAVOURITES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " +
            MoviesEntry.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
            MoviesEntry.COLUMN_MOVIE_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
            MoviesEntry.COLUMN_POSTER_URL + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            MoviesEntry.COLUMN_TITLE + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            MoviesEntry.COLUMN_PLOT + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            MoviesEntry.COLUMN_RATING_AVERAGE + " REAL NOT NULL," +
            MoviesEntry.COLUMN_RATING_COUNT + " INTEGER NOT NULL," +
            MoviesEntry.COLUMN_RELEASE_DATE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            MoviesEntry.COLUMN_MOVIE_TYPE + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
            "CHECK (" + MoviesEntry.COLUMN_MOVIE_TYPE + " IN (0,1,2))" + " );";

    //SQL statement to create the trailers table
    final String SQL_CREATE_TRAILERS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " +
            TrailersEntry.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
            TrailersEntry.COLUMN_VIDEO_ID + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY," +
            TrailersEntry.COLUMN_YOUTUBE_PATH + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            TrailersEntry.COLUMN_VIDEO_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            TrailersEntry.COLUMN_MOVIE_ID + " INTEGER NOT NULL, "
            //COLUMN_MOVIE_ID is a foreign key to favourites table
            + " FOREIGN KEY (" + TrailersEntry.COLUMN_MOVIE_ID + ") REFERENCES " +
            MoviesEntry.TABLE_NAME + " (" + MoviesEntry.COLUMN_MOVIE_ID + "), " +
            //Each trailer for a movie has to be unique
            " UNIQUE (" + TrailersEntry.COLUMN_VIDEO_ID + ", " +
            TrailersEntry.COLUMN_MOVIE_ID + ") ON CONFLICT REPLACE);";

    //SQL statement to create the reviews table
    final String SQL_CREATE_REVIEWS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " +
            ReviewsEntry.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
            ReviewsEntry.COLUMN_REVIEW_ID + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY," +
            ReviewsEntry.COLUMN_AUTHOR + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            ReviewsEntry.COLUMN_CONTENT + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            ReviewsEntry.COLUMN_MOVIE_ID + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
            //COLUMN_MOVIE_ID is a foreign key to the favourites table
            " FOREIGN KEY (" + ReviewsEntry.COLUMN_MOVIE_ID + ") REFERENCES " +
            MoviesEntry.TABLE_NAME + " (" + MoviesEntry.COLUMN_MOVIE_ID + "), " +
            //Each review for a movie has to be unique
            " UNIQUE (" + ReviewsEntry.COLUMN_REVIEW_ID + ", " +
            ReviewsEntry.COLUMN_MOVIE_ID + ") ON CONFLICT REPLACE);";

    db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_FAVOURITES_TABLE);
    db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_TRAILERS_TABLE);
    db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_REVIEWS_TABLE);
```

Can you help me to figure out how to construct the delete statement that will accomplish this?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384127/delete-sql-rows-where-ids-do-not-have-a-match-in-another-table) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967135/deleting-rows-from-sqlite-table-when-no-match-exists-in-another-table), I think you can do something like :

```
DELETE FROM Reviews
WHERE movie_id NOT IN (SELECT m.id 
                    FROM Movies m where movie_type = 2)

DELETE FROM Trailers
WHERE movie_id NOT IN (SELECT m.id 
                    FROM Movies m where movie_type = 2)

DELETE FROM Movies WHERE movie_type = 2
```