# MySQL Left Outer Join, Exclude Items in Second Table Belonging to User

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I have two tables in my MySQL database, one is a library of all of the books in the database, and the other is containing individual rows corresponding to which books are in a user's library.

For example:

**Library Table**

```
 `id`        `title`...
=====        ===========
  1          Moby Dick
  2          Harry Potter
```

**Collection Table**

```
 `id`        `user`      `book`
=====        ======      =======
  1            1            2
  2            2            2
  3            1            1
```

What I want to do is run a query that will show all the books that are *not* in a user's collection. I can run this query to show all the books not in *any* user's collection:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `library` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN  `collection` ON  `library`.`id` =  `collection`.`book` 
WHERE  `collection`.`book` IS NULL
```

This works just fine as far as I can tell. Running this in PHPMyAdmin will result in all of the books that aren't in the collection table.

However, how do I restrict that to a certain user? For example, with the above dummy data, I want book 1 to result if user `2` runs the query, and no books if user `1` runs the query.

Just adding a `AND user=[id]` doesn't work, and with my extremely limited knowledge of `JOIN` statements I'm not getting anywhere really.

Also, the ID of the results being returned (of query shown, which doesn't do what I want but does function) is 0-- how do I make sure the ID returned is that of `library.id`?

Comment: please show the actual table structure and give us the error (if any) you're encountering.  Your query mentions a field called "article" that's not in your table descriptions.

Comment: Oops-- I left it as article when I copied and pasted. It should be "book". I've changed the question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You'll have to narrow down your `LEFT JOIN` selection to only the books that a particular user has, *then* whatever is `NULL` in the joined table will be rows(books) for which the user does not have in his/her collection:

```
SELECT
    a.id,
    a.title
FROM
    library a
LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT book
        FROM collection
        WHERE user = <userid>
    ) b ON a.id = b.book
WHERE 
    b.book IS NULL
```

An alternative is:

```
SELECT
    a.id,
    a.title
FROM
    library a
WHERE 
    a.id NOT IN
    (
        SELECT book
        FROM collection
        WHERE user = <userid>
    )
```

However, the first solution is more optimal as MySQL will execute the `NOT IN` subquery once for each row rather than just once for the whole query. Intuitively, you would expect MySQL to execute the subquery once and use it as a list, but MySQL is not smart enough to distinguish between correlated and non-correlated subqueries.

As stated [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/subquery-restrictions.html):

> *"The problem is that, for a statement that uses an IN subquery, the
>   optimizer rewrites it as a correlated subquery."*

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly. This `JOIN` stuff, for whatever reason, is hard for me to wrap my head around...

Comment: Your last paragraph points to a link where `IN` subqueries are mentioned and not `NOT IN` subqueries. So, what you imply, that queries with `NOT IN` are not well optimized is wrong. See this great blog post: [NOT IN vs. NOT EXISTS vs. LEFT JOIN / IS NULL: MySQL](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/)

Comment: I believe it does not matter whether it's `NOT IN` or `IN`. The `NOT` just simply inverses the boolean returned from `IN`. Interesting article though +1

Comment: @ZaneBien, The article claimed that the run took the same amount of time. I think it's an optimization [specific to MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384127/delete-sql-rows-where-ids-do-not-have-a-match-in-another-table#comment-12936368). Very likely it looks at the query at a conceptual level and realize that it could have been rewritten as a join.

Answer (score 4):

How about this? It's just off the top of my head - I don't have access to a database to test on right now. (sorry)

```
SELECT 
   * 
FROM 
   library lib 
WHERE 
   lib.id NOT IN (
      SELECT 
         book 
      FROM 
         collection coll 
      WHERE 
         coll.user =[id]
   )
;
```

Comment: Ah... I see Andrew M beat me to it :O)

Comment: Thanks for the +1. I sorely need those, being completely new here :O)