# Mysql, delete unexisting entries

Tags: mysql

Let's imagine he have two tables

```
--
-- Table structure for table `user`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `phoneID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;


--
-- Table structure for table `phone`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `phone` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

So now I need create such query - I need delete all phone-entries from phone table where userID not exist (means user was deleted from user table and there is no such userID) using only one query.

My thoughts: we can use innerJoin to select all equal entries and then somehow we need delete others from phone table.

Please help with it.

WBR

Comment: Show us what you've got so far and we'll be happy to help you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delete sql rows where IDs do not have a match in another table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384127/delete-sql-rows-where-ids-do-not-have-a-match-in-another-table)

Comment: Yes, RMK thanks, it's duplicate. Close please. And thanks again.

Comment: Your table structure is rather unusual. Are you sure you nee to have a userID column in the phone table? Also, you're createing an unnecesary circular reference. If a user can only have one phone, leave phoneId in user and remove userID from phone. If a phone can only belong to one user, then remove phoneID from user and leave userID in phone. If a user can have more than one phone and a phone can be owned by more than one user, remove both foreign keys and add a new table with two columns, phoneID and userID that you'll use to join phones and users.

Comment: By the way, to me a phone table doesn't make sense unless a user can have more multiple phones.

Comment: It was a simple quick example, i think all readers understood what i was asking about.

Comment: Thank you user1954544; now I know that I am not alone, and there's at least one other person that gives a table a name that is singular (rather than plural), and naming what one row represents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
delete phone where userid not in (select user_id from user);
```

**BTW**, `PhoneID` should not be a field in the user table.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track. But what you need is a query that does an "anti-join", to get all rows from `phone` that don't have a matching row in `user`.

Write the query first:

```
SELECT p.*
  FROM `phone` p 
  LEFT
  JOIN `user` u 
    ON u.id = p.userID
 WHERE u.id IS NULL
```

Notice that this does a left join, so it's saying "get me ALL rows from phone, along with any matching rows from user". The trick to the anti-join is the WHERE clause, which says, "eliminate all the rows where we found a match". So what we are left with is rows from `phone` that didn't have a matching row in `user`.

After you verify this is the set of rows you want to delete, and then just change the SELECT keyword to DELETE:

```
-- SELECT p.*
DELETE p.*
  FROM `phone` p 
  LEFT
  JOIN `user` u 
    ON u.id = p.userID
 WHERE u.id IS NULL
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/delete.html

---

BTW: It's a bit unusual to have foreign key columns in each table referring to the other. There's no "rule" against it, but it's usually not required to satisfy a requirement that can be met by having a foreign key in just one table or the other. There are some corner cases where we'd need foreign keys pointing in both directions, but this a rare exception.