# Delete all rows in one table that aren't referenced by another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE  "status" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "created_at" datetime NOT NULL,    
    "updated_at" datetime NOT NULL);


CREATE TABLE "device" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "created_at" datetime NOT NULL,
    "updated_at" datetime NOT NULL,
    "last_status_object_id" integer REFERENCES "status" ("id"));
```

In the table "device", last_status_object_id references status.id.

I want to delete all status rows that are not referenced by "last_status_object_id".  I can't seem to figure out how to make this happen.  Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Are you really using mysql - the quotes are invalid (they should be backticks, probably)

Comment: @AD7six souble quotes are not invalid. They are ANSI standard and depending on the MySQL settings, they work there, too. See **[ANSI_QUOTES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes)**

Comment: @AD7six Sorry, not trying to confuse or mislead anyone.  This is the default django output sql.

Comment: You live and learn, me in this case (mysql has a setting for ansi quotes, django uses it) =)

Comment: Are you looking from something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384127/delete-sql-rows-where-ids-do-not-have-a-match-in-another-table)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DELETE
    status
FROM
    status
    LEFT JOIN device ON (status.id = last_status_object_id)
WHERE
    device.id IS NULL
```

Comment: I think this is not what I want - if the status row id is not contained anywhere in the device.last_status_object_id, I want to delete it.

Comment: @synic that is what `device.id IS NULL` does

Answer (score 2):

```
delete from status
where id not in (select last_status_object_id
                            from device);
```

Here we go, with demo in [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/19b06/2)

Comment: I don't want to delete any device rows.  I want to only delete a status row if it's ID is not referenced in device.last_status_object_id

Comment: sorry, copy and past mistake

Comment: Ok, pretend I didn't add the device_id on status.  I'm going to remove it, because it's confusing the question.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to delete all status rows that are not referenced by "last_status_object_id".

An easy way to express that is using [NOT EXISTS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html):

```
DELETE FROM 
    status
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM device WHERE last_status_object_id = status.id)
```