# How to delete data NOT IN View

Tags: sql, view, ssms

How do I delete data that is not in the view, the view is made up of 8 different tables using intersect
they all have 'country' column in them and I want to delete country that is not in the view (vw_Countries).

I tried this two ways and I get this error message.

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 24
>  Invalid column name
> 'vw_Countries'.

```
Delete from [WorldFoodProduction].[dbo].[CO2_Data]
         where country not in( vw_Countries).

Delete  [WorldFoodProduction].[dbo].[CO2_Data]
         where country not in( vw_Countries).
```

Comment: Did you mean `NOT IN (SELECT country FROM vw_Countries)`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete sql rows where IDs do not have a match from another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384127/delete-sql-rows-where-ids-do-not-have-a-match-from-another-table)

Comment: This is not MySQL, please tag with your actual database.

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
DELETE FROM [WorldFoodProduction].[dbo].[CO2_Data]
WHERE country NOT IN (SELECT country 
                        FROM vw_Countries)
```

You need to use a select statement to select the value from the view.